# How to avoid reading in data every time you run your R program

Tags: r

In my R file, the first task is reading in 24 excel files with each of them 8 tabs. This takes a while, because the usual sorting and column naming etc has to be done.

What is the best strategy now to continue to work without reading in the file all the time?

One option I can think of is to save the work space and open it every time when you do analysis work, but are there other and maybe better options?

Thank you.

Comment: it is saving the workspace, you can customize with save.image("file.file") if not in working dir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of saving all the work space, save just the data.frames you've read. Let's put you read some data.frames from xls files and you name them `data1`, `data2` and `data3`. To save them just execute

> save(data1, data2, data3 ,file="filename.Rdata")

and to load them execute

> load("filename.Rdata")

it will add `data1`, `data2` and `data3` to your work space.

By the way, it works for any objects in R, including lists, functions and whatever you want, not just data.frames.

Comment: If you have 24 data.frames you definitely should put them into a list or environment and save this.

Comment: All the monthly excel files are stored in one dataframe that I wish to save for future analysis work.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer, here's a little trick to extend it to build some kind of cache, which is particularly interesting when reading data from online sources etc.

```
 # load data 
 if (file.exists("cache/my_data.RData") { 
 load("cache/my_data.RData")
 } else {
 # read.csv, do whatever pre-processing
 # connect to a remote db ...  
 save(my_object,file="cache/my_data.RData")
}
```

note that this works also with functions or graphs as @Rufo said.